# Strange CoordinatorLayout/AppBarLayout behavior

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"/>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Seems, the AppBarLayout becomes "ontop" view once the CollapsingToolbarLayout reaches the minHeight height. See the screenshots:

[image] [image] [image]

**Question 1**: Why it behaves like that?

**Question 2**: Is it possible to prevent that? I need that the square was on top while the CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed to its minimum height.

Answer (score 0):

**ANCHORS**

I think the reason for your problem is the anchor and the height attribute of the **`AppBarLayout`**. What I suggest doing:

- Set the **`height`** attribute of the **`AppBarLayout`** to **`wrap_content`**
- Set the **`max_height` or `height`** of your **`CollapsingToolbarLayout`** to 200dp
- Set the anchor of your **`View`** to the **`CollapsingToolbarLayout`**

I honestly hope I helped, I'm still quite new to Android but if I have figured it out for you let me know.
-Daniel

Comment: Thanks. However that does not help. The only thing that changes the behavior is the minHeight. Once it is added the issue occurs.